# How to check if multiple elements do NOT have focus using jquery

Tags: jquery

How do I check if 2 elements do not have focus?

I have a text box and drop down list. If neither of them are in focus, I want to hide the drop down.

Can I check with the following code?

```
if (!$("#dropdown,#textbox").is(":focus"))
```

Comment: Try `if( !$('#dropdown').is(':focus') && !$('#textbox').is('focus') ) {...}`

Comment: You should just try your code: http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 4):

```
if ($("#dropdown,#textbox").is(":focus")) //its valid it will validate any
{
    $("#dropdown").show();
}else{
    $("#dropdown").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[document.activeElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.activeElement) will return the currently focused element, then all you have to do is check that the ID does not match `dropdown` or `textbox`, no jQuery needed for this!

```
var focused = document.activeElement.id;

if ( focused != 'dropdown' && focused != 'textbox') {
   document.getElementById('dropdown').style.display = 'none';
}
```

or jQuery version:

```
$('#dropdown').toggle( !$("#dropdown, #textbox").is(":focus") );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if ( !$('#dropdown').is(':focus') && !$("#textbox").is(':focus') ) { your function here }
```

Comment: That will always evaluate to `true`, since `$("#dropdown")` is an object (and therefore true).

Comment: Not gonna work, you'll need the `not` on both selectors. **Edit:** I edited your answer to work.